# Retrieving minimum value becomes every slow in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, performance, b-tree

I found a strange problem on Postgresql which retrieving minimum value from a small table with 11 row spent almost 200ms.

Initializing a data, turning off autovacuum and starting it.Then executing below sqls.

```
create table test1(a int);
insert into test1 select generate_series(1, 10000000);
vacuum analyze test1;
create index on test1(a);
delete from test1 where a < 9999990;`
```

Executing sql
select min(a) from test1;
select max(a) from test2;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwCQ0.png)

Above image shows spending 197.443 ms to obtain minimum value but getting maximum value only spent 0.084 ms. They both used index only scan. Why them have a such big difference between getting minimum and maximum value. I know vacuuming this table can resolve this performance problem, but I don't know the reason. In my opinion, index only scan is the fastest retrieve method. It's unconceivable. Expecting someone can explain it. Thank you first!

Comment: I think, order of query execution is possible gets this difference. Index pages are in memory after first query.

Comment: Other difference index scan ``forward``(min) vs ``backward``(max). In your case  it is clear that ``backward``  is faster. There only 1 index read. You can see ``Heap Fetches`` value in execution plan.

Comment: Index bloat because of your DELETE. When removing such a large percentage of the content, you might want to reindex.

Comment: The index is full (literally 99.9999%) of dead entries that still need to be "walked" to get to the first non-dead one. Simple maintenance will normalize the situation.

Comment: @ValNik, hello ValNik, inverse order of execution has a similar result. And it seems that index only scan does not access heap.

Comment: @Frank Heikens, hello Frank Heikens. I can not reindex it even if I want it since my customer does not permit it.

Comment: @The Impaler, hello The Impaler, I agree with you. The time it spent is scanning almost the whole btree. But I can not use maintenance operation since my customer does not permit me to do that. They have fixed sqls and operations. I am tring to figure out how to achieve a POC to solve this problem which only gets a minimum and maximum value by index (only) scan. Thank you!

Comment: "...I can not use maintenance operation since my customer does not permit me to do that..." -- That doesn't make business sense. Maintenance tasks are normal and are typically done at night, every night, or according to a specific schedule. If they are not done, then the application will deteriorate over time.

Comment: No maintenance allowed? That tells me that the application is end of life and there is no problem at all

Comment: Try use ``create index on test1(a desc);``  My be more optimal using of index.

Comment: @ValNik The problem is the lack of maintenance, not the index itself. Your proposal for a new index will suffer from the same problem without maintenance. And reindexing the current index will already solve the issue.

Comment: A see, maintenance (reindex) is not possible. My be possible create index with desc order permanently (1 time). Table (and index) heavily skewed after deleting a significant number of rows. Keeping the index in reverse order can reduce the impact.

Answer (score -1):

after delete it is left with 11 rows only. min and max timing you may be taking immediately after delete ? after few executions it is coming same time. but if you have huge data and execute min number of times  then you will see difference in time between
select min(a) from test11;
select a from test11 order by a limit 1;
Second is much faster.

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer, select a from test1 order by a limit 1 has a similar result.